# Recommended FXO Gateway for UK analogue lines

Tags: voip, asterisk, telephony

Can anybody recommend any FXO gateway devices to connect analogue telephone lines to an Asterisk VoIP system.

Requirements:

- Minimum of 4 ports.
- Enterprise grade - quality is more important than price.
- For UK analogue telephone lines. - I don't know if this makes a difference or not?

I'd also be interested to hear bad experiences, so I can get an idea of which devices to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard that the Digium cards are ideal for interfacing Asterisk with the UK Analogue PSTN. Digium was started by one of the initial developer of Asterisk, so compatibility is there by design.

Digium AEX410 looks like it would suit your needs...

http://www.digium.com/en/products/analog/

Answer (score 1):

I'v tried lots of gateways in south-america, where every country is a bit off all known standards on analoge lines, and have always had very good results with Audiocodes. They make solid hardware used as embedded parts in lots of brand-name telephone systems, so they are no new kid in the block.

I suggest you try them out.

Digium cards work pretty well, but on some countries they lack proper CallerID support.